# RevMob showPopup does't exist in the latest version

Tags: android, popup, revmob

I want to upgrade RevMob library version, 
in old version I have functionality to display in fullscreen and in popup like this:

```
revMob.showFullscreen(current_activity);
revMob.showPopup(current_activity);
```

In new verion **showFullscreen** works, but **showPopup** was deprecated, how I can to use popup ?

Answer (score 0):

according to [Google Play Monetization Policies](https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/ads/deceptive/), the Pop Up ad unit has been removed:

> Ads must not simulate or impersonate the user interface of any app, notification, or warning elements of an operating system. It must be clear to the user which app is serving each ad.